# How I can detect that my Android app on the foreground?

Tags: android

I'm trying to know my or no application on the foreground using the next code from BroadcastReceiver:

```
boolean inForeground = false;
ActivityManager actMngr = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = actMngr.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo pi : runningAppProcesses) {
    if (context.getPackageName().equals(pi.processName)) {
      inForeground = pi.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
    }
}
```

But this code always return **true**, even when my application in background.
I found next solution:

```
if (actMngr.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())){
  Log.d(TAG, "My");
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Not my");
}
```

Is this code correct or not?
Or maybe somebody know more simple variant?
Thanks!

Comment: Your second solution is almost correct, I think. You need to check the `numRunning` flag of the RunningTaskInfo returned by `get(0)`. The top activity may be stopped and persisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way is to track your foreground status using `onResume()` and `onPause()`. Refer to the [Activity lifecycle model](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: But if I have more than 100 activity and I need to know my or no app from **BroadcastReceiver**? And **BroadcastReceiver** doesn't reference even to the one Activity, because it is defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That is, why do you need to know if the foreground activity is from the same package?